# IntelliJ IDEA Maven when packaging ,excluding files from compilation doesn't work in

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am running "package" from the IntelliJ maven lifecycle menu item

I want to exclude the properties files in src/main/resources/*.properties from the jar file

In my pom.xml , i have

```
    <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
            <artifactId>activejdbc-instrumentation</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

yet when i run the task i see in the output

```
[INFO] -----------------------< groupId:MyApp >------------------------
[INFO] Building MyApp 0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MyApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
```

and then when i do `jar -vtf MyApp-0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep properties`

I still see the properties i do not want in the jar

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use maven jar plugin to exclude the resources folder.

Comment: Best and simplest solution is: Remove them from `src/main/resources` because the convention is that everything which is in `src/main/resources` will be packaged...

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for the response. so if the convention is to keep the stuff in the resources, what is the best practice for dev and prod resources environments?

thanks

Comment: Why do you need different things for prod/dev? What kind of properties have you in `src/main/resources` which are environment specific?

Comment: @khmarbaise i have a run time properties file that contains remote servers (prod and sandbox)

Comment: This means your build is environment specific. Usually you should configure such things from outside not within the app... the question is what kind of app is this? Command line app? Then I would give such thing via command line (system properties) or external properties file...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, it is a CLI, i will pass in a config file in the args